# How clear a user entry in C++?

Tags: c++, validation, input

Well, suppose i have the following situation: the program require to user enter five characters:

```
Enter five characters:
```

And the user enter only four characters:

```
Enter five characters: four
```

How clear just the user entry, in case, "four"? Because the only way what i knows is clear the console e show the message again.

Thanks!

Comment: google for `cursor repositioning`

Comment: You can output a backspace (assuming you or they did not enter a newline), but because you have dumb users, just give up since they will break that too.

Comment: In many cases it's probably more helpful to print a message like "only four characters entered" and _not_ clear what they typed, so they can see what was wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can `cout` a `'\b'` (backspace character) to move cursor back one position.

For example, in order to delete last 4 `char`s:

```
cout << "\b\b\b\b";
```

Comment: I had thought of this, but the problem is that after the user press the ENTER key, this enter a newline and isn't possible use the backspace character to delete the user entry. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Create a solution for this: http://pastebin.com/wc6rbcT5

In this case, the class can be used in this way:

```
// Example:
int main() {
        char input[ 100 ];

        UserInput userin;
        userin.options.length = 5;
        userin.options.restrictEntry = "numbers";
        userin.run( "Enter five numbers: ", input );

        cout << input;
}
```

Thanks everyone.